# Digital Engagement WhatsApp Channel not initiating Messaging Sessions

Tags: digital-engagement

Digital Engagement for WhatsApp and it is not creating messaging sessions.
Did troubleshooting by this guide https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352588&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1 and submitted a case to Salesforce.
Salesforce replied that everything is correctly set up on that channel from their side. 
How do we find the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before all carefully walk through this FAQ
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352588&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1

If all items from the link are checked, there is nothing you can do about WhatsApp integration. As it is black-box mostly.
Only thing is to push on Salesforce support and Facebook support and read carefully replies from both sides. 
Turned out the problem was on the Salesforce.com side to setup integration correctly from the first time.